# Jackson Nested Object Deserialization into property

Tags: java, json, hibernate, jackson

Suppose I have a json object that looks like:

```
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "john doe"
    spouse: 2
  }
```

and the class I want it to deserialize it to:

```
class Person{

  private Long id;
  private String name;

  private Person spouse;

  //getters/setters
}
```

Is there any way to tell jackson to expand the `spouse: 2` property into a new Person POJO with `id=2` when deserializing the JSON?

I have run into this issue as a result of deserializing JSON into persistent entities and would like to be able to easily persist the relationships between these entities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aside from a full deserializer, there is a simpler way: define a POJO with a single int-arg constructor like so:

```
class Person {
   int id;
   public Person(int id) {
     this.id = id;
   }
}
```

This actually works, as Jackson will try to find limited number of special constructors (single-arg public constructors that that take String, int, long, double or boolean).

You can optionally also denote these with @JsonCreator -- and if constructor is not public, you must do it, to make it discoverable. But for public ctors this is not needed.

Comment: This is the option I ended up going with.  It's simple and intuitive.  It doesn't nicely hookup with the persistence tier, but that's a whole other question.

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible of course for Jackson to infer a fully populated `Person` object representing the spouse from the number `2`. You would likely need to register a custom deserializer that checks if the input is an integer, and if so, looks up the spouse from wherever it is stored. I have not done this kind of thing for classes that contain references to themselves (e.g. your `Person` contains a `Person`) so I can only give you rough guidance.

I believe this may only work with Jackson version `1.9` or later. Basically, you can register a module with the object mapper that tells Jackson to use a custom deserializer.

```
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("PeopleModule", new Version(1, 1, 0, null);
module.addDeserializer(Person.class, new JacksonPersonDeserializer());

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(module);
```

Alternately on the `Person` class itself, you can do something like:

```
class Person {

  @JsonDeserialize(using=JacksonPersonDeserializer.class)
  Person spouse;
}
```

This works before `1.9` but pollutes your object. Either way, you will need to write a custom deserializer.

Comment: I figured I would need to do something with annotations and Custom deserializers.  I wasn't aware that the `@JsonDeserialize` annotation was valid on fields so I'll go down that route.

Comment: Hmmmm. It may actually only work on the setter. Worth trying on the field though.

Comment: In general, this is true -- Jackson can not do structural conversions. But case of int/double/String is special, see my answer.

Comment: On @JsonDeserialize -- yes, works on fields, setters; but before 1.9 had to be on one that gets used. 1.9 combines annotations, so this should work even if you have setter and getter (formerly had to be on setter).

Comment: I'm trying to write a Jackson module, and its purpose is to provide some specific functionality **seamlessly**. I don't want to create a special constructor like in the accepted answer because I don't want to touch the POJOs.
How could I accomplish this using the custom deserializer route?
Please, check my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19008853/jackson-deserialize-json-property-into-object

Thanks!