# Jackson deserialize json property into object

Tags: java, json, jackson

I need to deserialize the following json:

```
{
    //...
    "foo_id":1
    //...
}
```

Into an object of class Foo with its `id` property set to the `foo_id` json property.

I need to do this within a custom deserializer.
What is the most easy way to accomplish this?

I was thinking to somehow "transform" the json to

```
{
    //...
    "foo_id":{
        "id":1
    }
    //...
}
```

and then delegate this back to Jackson.

In this case, the object is of type Foo, but there are others which might not be of this class. Also, in this case, that json is a number, but I would like to support if it was a string as well.
So, I need a kind of generic way to do this, that's why I think delegating back to Jackson might be a good idea.

No annotations allowed. Suppose you're already writing the Deserializer for this property.

Comment: What do you mean no annotations allowed? no annotations at all? you can specify the deserilizer for the jsonproperty using the annotations and inside that you can distinguish between integer and string....

Comment: I'm trying to write a module for Jackson. The idea is to keep the POJOs untouched.
I already wrote a BeanDeserializerModifier in which I can assign any deserializer to that property. The problem is now the deserializer.

Comment: So in your deserilizer you need to check the foo_id filed and the value if the value is instanceof String you return forexample foostr type and if it is integer you return foointeger type. If I am right I can post some code as an answer here!?

Comment: That code may help a lot, thanks, but that's not *exactly* what I need here.
The thing is that I don't know if the id property in Foo class will be a number or a string, or whatever. Ideally the Deserializer shouldn't care about it.
What I need is to check the foo_id field and create a instance of Foo class with its id set to foo_id property, whatever that is.
Please contribute as you can. We might get some ideas from that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](http://programmerbruce.blogspot.com/2011/05/deserialize-json-with-jackson-into.html). Here is a code that I think might help you to get some ideas.

```
public class MyDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer< Message >
{
@Override
public Message deserialize( JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext arg1 ) throws IOException,
        JsonProcessingException
{
    ObjectMapper mapper = (ObjectMapper) jp.getCodec();  
    ObjectNode root = (ObjectNode) mapper.readTree(jp);  
    Class<? extends Message> subClass = null;  
    Iterator<Entry<String, JsonNode>> elementsIterator = root.getFields();  
    while (elementsIterator.hasNext())  
    {  
      Entry<String, JsonNode> element = elementsIterator.next();  
      String name = element.getKey();  
      if ("foo_id".equals(name))  
      {  
         if(element.getValue().isInt())
            subClass = FooInteger.Class;  
         break;  
      }  
    }  
    if (subClass == null) return null;  
    return mapper.readValue(root, subClass);    
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered use of [mix-in annotations](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2009/08/entry_305.html)? With Jackson 2.2, you could also use converters to do two-step processing (`@JsonDeserialize(converter=MyConverter.class`).